# Error when publishing story with Facebook Open Graph

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm trying to publish a story but Open Graph returning me this error: domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5

I use these permissions:

```
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @ "status_update" @ "publish_actions" @ "publish_stream" @ "user_likes" @ "create_event", nil];
```

And the code I use to create the history:

```
NSMutableDictionary * item = [FBGraphObject graphObject];      
[Item setObject: @ "http://mysite.com.br/cardapio/6/burger-de-carne" forKey: @ "object"];

NSMutableDictionary * action = (<FBOpenGraphAction> NSMutableDictionary *) [FBGraphObject graphObject];
 [Action setObject: item forKey: @ "Like"];

  [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath: @ "me/og.like" graphObject: action  completionHandler: ^ (* FBRequestConnection connection,   id result,  NSError * error)
 {  NSString * alertText;

                              if(! error) 
                             { alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "Open Graph Posted action, id:% @", [Result objectForKey: @ "id"]]; 
                              Else { 
                                     alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "error:% @ domain =, code =% d",  error.domain, error.code];  }

 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @ "Result"  message: alertText delegate: nil  cancelButtonTitle: @ "Thanks!"  otherButtonTitles: nil]  show];
  }];
```

Comment: What's the text of the error you're receiving?

Comment: 2012-11-19 16:57:29.521 myApp[14696:c07] Error: HTTP status code: 400
2012-11-19 16:57:29.524 myApp[14696:c07] Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x6851fe0 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey=<CFBasicHash 0x684eb60 [0x179fb48]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
 1 : <CFString 0x5b91c [0x179fb48]>{contents = "code"} = <CFNumber 0x684db30 [0x179fb48]>{value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}

Comment: I mean the error from Facebook's side - i don't think that's an error from the server?

Comment: Could you show code around how you set the session?

Comment: conssegui solves the two problems were the parameter me / and I actually og.like / og.likes I was uzando two NSMutableDictionary one inside the other was for most uses only one